# How to search for 26 tabs in a field

Tags: unix, grep

can anyone help

i have a file containing tab separated values, there should be 26 tabs per record but some have more i want to copy out of the file those record that do have 26 per line so i can ingest the file

something like 
`cat infile |grep "/t"*<26 times> >outfile`

thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may be possible with grep, but awk is designed for such tasks.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}; {if ( NF == 26 ) print $0}' infile > outfile
```

awk has numerous built in variables, FS=FieldSeperator, you can set that to any value, but here '\t' is the C-language-like constant value representing the tab char. The '|' (pipe) char is also popular.

`BEGIN { ... code ... }` is a block of code that executes before processing takes place.
The final bit, is that code inside the non-BEGIN block, i.e. `{ if ( NF ... }` is action that takes place for each line that is read.

NF=Number(of)Fields. So you can easily filter by number of fields in a file.

NR=Number(of)Records.

Also note that for `grep` or `awk`, there is no need to use `cat file | ...`, both utiltites read any files that are passed in on the command line, i.e. grep .... file1 file2 ... filen

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep '^\([^\t]*\t\){26}[^\t]*$'
```

What it does is find lines that have 26 tabs possibly separated by non-tab stuff.
Depending on your version of grep, you might need to try:

grep -P  '^([^\t]*\t){26}[^\t]*$'

to get full perl regexp support

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
awk 'NF==26' infile > outfile
```

No need to specify the FS as tab is a default one, no need to specify an action as awk default action is to print the matching record.